# Custom 'full screen' height for the Material UI Dialog modal component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Currently, I am using the fullScreen property on the Material UI Dialog component (which acts as a modal on the screen) as recommended in the docs, like this:

```
import useMediaQuery from '@material-ui/core/useMediaQuery';


function MyComponent() {

  const theme = useTheme();

  const fullScreen = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('sm'));

  return <Dialog fullScreen={fullScreen} />

}
```

Unfortunately, this causes the Dialog modal to cover the navbar at the top of the screen. I would like to override the height of the Dialog modal, but I am not sure how.

Is anyone able to help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just pass a className to it & give it the top value equal to your AppBar's height. here is the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-0ugq8?file=/demo.js:686-696)

Comment: This worked for me!! Thank you so much!! I was wracking my brain for days!!